# Register two services of same concrete type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I want to register two services of the same type, (not using an interface) with different constructor arguments.

e.g. so far I have:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(x => new WeatherForecastService("param1", "param2"));
builder.Services.AddScoped(x => new WeatherForecastService("param3", "param4"));
```

I have seen that I can create a "named" type but it doesn't seem to work when sending in constructor arguments.

Ideally something like this would be nice:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(x => new WeatherForecastService("param1", "param2")).Name("my_first_service_named");

builder.Services.AddScoped(x => new WeatherForecastService("param3", "param4")).Name("my_second_service_named");
```

Comment: This isn't possible in the default DI implementation built in to .NET. It might work if you use Ninject or Autofac perhaps.

Comment: How do you expect to retrieve the class from the DI container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using .NET dependency injection library (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`)?
However, the principle applies no matter the IoC library. Only the registration would differ.

You can create a new concrete type, of course.
But since you only have different configurations of the same type, depending on the exact context you could introduce an abstract factory or a factory delegate.
The factory allows to create the same instance with different configurations. The advantage of factories is that they allow to create different configurations dynamically (where the required configuration is not know in advance).

Depending on the actual IoC library, you may have additional library specific options. For example some support named services in tandem with attributes.

### Solution 1: Factory Delegate

Most IoC libraries support factory delegates to realize simple factories. You simply would define a `Func` as constructor parameter and the register the product type. Most will automatically create the delegate for you. .NET IoC requires you to register the `Func` explicitly:

Register the factory delegate:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Func<string, string, WeatherForecastService>>(
  serviceProvider => 
    (parameter1, parameter2) => new WeatherForecastService(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Declare the factory as dependency and use it:

```cs
class SomeType
{
  private WeatherForecastService WeatherForecastService { get; }
  public SomeType(Func<string, string, WeatherForecastService>, serviceFactory)
  {
    this.WeatherForecastService = serviceFactory.Invoke("param1", "param2");
  }
}

class SomeOtherType
{
  private WeatherForecastService WeatherForecastService { get; }
  public SomeType(Func<string, string, WeatherForecastService>, serviceFactory)
  {
    this.WeatherForecastService = serviceFactory.Invoke("param3", "param4");
  }
}
```

### Solution 2: Abstract Factory

If the configurations are not dynamic, you can create a factory that returns pre-configured instances (of course dynamic configurations, where the caller explicitly decides how to configure the instance is possible as well):

Define the factory:

```cs
class WeatherForecastServiceFactory : IWeatherForecastService
{
  public WeatherForecastService CreateEuropeService() 
    => new WeatherForecastService("param1", "param2"); 

  public WeatherForecastService CreateAfricaService() 
    => new WeatherForecastService("param3", "param4");
}
```

Register the factory:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWeatherForecastServiceFactory, WeatherForecastServiceFactory>();
```

Declare the dependency:

```cs
class SomeType
{
  private WeatherForecastService ForecastEurope { get; }
  public SomeType(IWeatherForecastServiceFactory serviceFactory)
  {
    this.ForecastEurope = serviceFactory.CreateEuropeService();
  }
}
```

### Solution 3: Encapsulate configuration (recommended, most convenient and robust)

In case of static configuration variations, an alternative to using abstract factories (solution 2) is to define a dedicated class for each configuration. This solution gives you much welcomed compiler support to ensure that the correct configuration is used: this eliminates the potential for a severe bug:

```cs
class WeatherForecastEurope : WeatherForecastService
{
  public WeatherForecastEurope() : base("param1", "param2")
  {}
}

class WeatherForecastAfrica : WeatherForecastService
{
  public WeatherForecastEurope() : base("param3", "param4")
  {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, you can register multiple instances of the same class to the DI container. When you retrieve the class from the container, you will retrieve the latest registered instance of that class.

It is possible to obtain all the registered instances of a class.

```
public class WeatherForecastController
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<WeatherForecastService> _weatherForecastServices;

    public WeatherForecastController(IEnumerable<WeatherForecastService> weatherForecastServices)
    {
       _weatherForecastServices = weatherForecastServices;
    }
}
```

In this example all registered instances of the WeatherForecastService class will be available through the _weatherForecastServices field. You could filter them in the methods that use them or filter them inside the constructor to only keep a single instance of the WeatherForecastService class.

Comment: While this would work, you create certain issues: **a)** You break encapsulation. Usually you don't want a particular type to have access to other types that it doesn't need or is not meant to use. **b)** This solution results in creation of *all* instances only to allow the depending type to pick a single one. This can (and usually is) quite expensive (note each type potentially has its own dependency graph and potentially allocates expensive resources).

Comment: **c)** You will end up with an ugly switch in your constructor in order to filter your required type or type configuration. If the application gets extended i.e. new implementations are added this technique is prone to bugs if the conditions to distinguish the instance variations become ambiguous. Picking the wrong type would result in wrong behavior which would remain undetected, because the type is basically compatible (it i s the *same* type). Using different concrete types is the most robust solution as it gives you compiler support to prevent using the wrong type.